# Parity: What is a snapshot?

Tags: parity, snapshot

The [Configuring Parity](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity) wiki page says:

> ```
> Snapshot Options:
>   --at BLOCK            Take a snapshot at the given block, which may be an
>                         index, hash, or 'latest'. Note that taking snapshots at 
>                         non-recent blocks will only work with --pruning archive
>                         (default: latest)
> ```

What is a snapshot?

Does it cause the whole blockchain at that block to be saved to disk in a separate file? If so, where are these stored?

Comment: Snapshots are not verified locally correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The snapshot is stored on your disk in a directory like

```
~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains/ethereum/db/906a34e69aec8c0d/snapshot/
```

and is currently around 1.5 GB in size. It contains the latest state at `BLOCK` (all accounts, all balances, all contracts, all execution states, etc.) and the last 30_000 blocks before that state.

Comment: Is this number 30,000 configurable somehow? I'm trying to minimise disk usage.

Comment: Just run with `--no-periodic-snapshot`: Disable automated snapshots which usually occur once every 10000 blocks.

Comment: @Rando I've synced with fast mode, and after 5340000 BLK, it was synced normal, and now parity making snapshot at 5420000.
Is there offline dump or can api access on whole snapshot?

I've changed option not prune blocks (default : 64) -> to 1000000